# How to pass address of 2-d array to a double pointer which (**a)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have this function

- int findMax(int **a,int row,int column)

  and i am  having  2-d array which is a[10][10].
- Now what should i do so i can pass the address of this array to my function pointer that is **a ?

i saw other answers but the problem remain the same i have to pass the address but whenever i am trying to do this my compiler starts giving error and says cannot convert int to int and type mismatch error.

Give me your valuable suggestions and idea guys how should i do this?

Here is my code.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

  int findMax(int **a,int r,int c);

 int main()
 {
    int a[10][10],i,j,mx,r,c;


    printf("Enter the number of rows in the matrix\n");
     scanf("%d",&r);
     printf("Enter the number of columns in the matrix\n");
     scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("Enter the elements in the matrix\n");

    for(i=1;i<=r;i++)
    {
      for(j=1;j<=c;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("The matrix is\n");
    for(i=1;i<=r;i++)
     {
      for(j=1;j<=c;j++)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    mx=findMax((int **)a,r,c);
    printf("The maximum elements in the matrix is %d\n",mx);
    return 0;
    }

    int findMax(int **a,int r,int c)
     {
    int t,i,j;
    t=a[0][0];
    for(i=1;i<=r;i++)
     {
      for(j=1;j<=c;j++)
      {
            if(a[i][j]>t)
                 t=a[i][j];
      }
      }
    return (t);
```

Comment: Note that this program has several problems - not only the reference to the array, but eg. array indices in C are 0 based (see the findMax function!0

Comment: @jcoppens i have done that alteration but what about the main problem how to solve that?

Comment: You did *not* correct the errors. Look at [this article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/)

Comment: But there is a problem whenever i am trying to execute it gives processor fault.

Comment: What is the exact message?

Comment: In my function i have started the array from 1 because i have already stored the value of t=a[0][0].As i have to find the maximum so that's why.

Comment: @jcoppens message is " 0x1D07:0x0140 Processor Fault ".

Comment: No idea - I never had that error. But if you still have your indices starting from 1, you are probably address outside the array and touching memory which is not owned by the program. There should probably be a segmentation fault too.

Comment: @jcoppens So instead of doing that what should I do?????

Comment: You should read up on arrays in C. All indices start at 0